# Generating all permutations excluding cyclic rotations

Tags: c++, algorithm, rotation, permutation

So I need an algorithm to generate all permutations of a list of numbers excluding cyclic rotations (e.g. [1,2,3] == [2,3,1] == [3,1,2]).

When there is at least 1 unique number in the sequence it is fairly straight forward, take out that unique number, generate all permutations of the remaining numbers (but with a small modification to the 'standard' permutations algorithm) and add the unique number to the front.

For generating the permutations I've found that it's necessary to change the permutations code to:

```
def permutations(done, options)
    permuts = []
    seen = []
    for each o in options
        if o not in seen
            seen.add(o)
            permuts += permutations(done+o, options.remove(o))
    return permuts
```

Only using each unique number in options once means that you don't get 322 twice.

This algorithm still outputs rotations when there are no unique elements, e.g. for [1,1,2,2] it would output [1,1,2,2], [1,2,2,1] and [1,2,1,2] and the first two are cyclic rotations.

So is there an efficient algorithm that would allow me to generate all the permutations without having to go through afterwards to remove cyclic rotations?

If not, what would be the most efficient way to remove cyclic rotations?

**NOTE**: this is *not* using Python, but rather C++.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [generating all unique circular permutations of a multiset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467914/is-there-an-algorithm-to-generate-all-unique-circular-permutations-of-a-multiset)? There are some good answers there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about testing each of the permutations you output, looking for a cyclic rotation that's "lexically" earlier than the one you've got. If there is one, don't return it - it will have been enumerated somewhere else.

Choosing a "unique" first element, if one exists, helps you optimize. You know if you fix the first element, and it's unique, then you can't possibly have duplicated it with a rotation. On the other hand, if there's no such unique element, just choose the one that occurs the least. That way you only need to check for cyclic rotations that have that first element. (Example, when you generate [1,2,2,1] - you only need to check [1,1,2,2], not [2,2,1,1] or [2,1,1,2]).

---

OK, pseudocode... clearly O(n!), and I'm convinced there's no smarter way, since the case "all symbols different" obviously has to return (n-1)! elements.

```
// generate all permutations with count[0] 0's, count[1] 1's...
def permutations(count[])
    if(count[] all zero)
        return just the empty permutation;
    else
        perms = [];
        for all i with count[i] not zero
            r = permutations(copy of count[] with element i decreased);
            perms += i prefixed on every element of r
        return perms;

// generate all noncyclic permutations with count[0] 0's, count[1] 1's...
def noncyclic(count[])
    choose f to be the index with smallest count[f];
    perms = permutations(copy of count[] with element f decreased);
    if (count[f] is 1)
        return perms;
    else
        noncyclic = [];
        for each perm in perms
            val = perm as a value in base(count.length);
            for each occurence of f in perm
                test = perm rotated so that f is first
                tval = test as a value in base(count.length);
                if (tval < val) continue to next perm;
            if not skipped add perm to noncyclic;
        return noncyclic;

// return all noncyclic perms of the given symbols
def main(symbols[])
    dictionary = array of all distinct items in symbols;
    count = array of counts, count[i] = count of dictionary[i] in symbols
    nc = noncyclic(count);
    return (elements of nc translated back to symbols with the dictionary)
```

Comment: Would it not be more efficient (at least in terms of memory) to have the check if it's the 'smallest' rotation in the permutations function rather than noncyclc so you don't have to store so much in perms, or would the gain be pretty much negligible?

Comment: You'd have to pass state all the way down through the recursion... and be able to do tests like "since my first f was followed by an x, make sure any other f's I add are followed by x or greater". Seems pretty tough.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by passing down the state, I just passed down the 'anchor' when I coded up a quick test and had a small function that found the 'minimum' rotation and compared it to the current permutation

Answer (score 10):

For the case of permutations where all numbers are distinct, this is simple. Say the numbers are `1,2,...,n`, then generate all permutations of `1,2,...,n-1` and stick `n` at the front. This gives all permutations of the full set modulo cyclic rotations. For example, with `n=4`, you would do

```
4 1 2 3
4 1 3 2
4 2 1 3
4 2 3 1
4 3 1 2
4 3 2 1
```

This ensures that some cyclic rotation of each permutation of `1,2,3,4` appears exactly once in the list.

For the general case where you want permutations of a multiset (repeated entries allowed), you can use a similar trick. Remove all instances of the largest letter `n` (similar to ignoring the `4` in the above example) and generate all permutations of the remaining multiset. The next step is to put the `n`s back into the permutations in canonical ways (similar to putting the `4` at the beginning in the above example).

This is really just a case of finding all [Lyndon words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) to generate [necklaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29)

Comment: Didn't know they were called necklaces, that probably would have made researching it easier, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is going to involve a bit of [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) usage, [`set()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set), and some good ol' fashioned set difference.  Bear in mind, the runtime for finding a permutation will still be O(n!).  My solution won't do it in-line, either, but there *may* be a much more elegant solution that allows you to do so (and doesn't involve `itertools.permutations`). For this purpose, this is the straightforward way to accomplish the task.

Step 1:  Algorithm for generating cycles, using the first element given.  For a list `[1, 1, 2, 2]`, this will give us `[1, 1, 2, 2],  [1, 2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1, 1]`.

```
def rotations(li):
    count = 0
    while count < len(li):
        yield tuple(li)
        li = li[1:] + [li[0]]
        count += 1
```

Step 2:  Importing `itertools.permutations` to give us the permutations in the first place, then setting up its results into a `set`.

```
from itertools import permutations
perm = set(permutations([1, 1, 2, 2]))
```

Step 3:  Using the generator to give us our own set, with the cycles (something we want to rid ourselves of).

```
cycles = set(((i for i in rotations([1, 1, 2, 2]))))
```

Step 4:  Apply set difference to each and the cycles are removed.

```
perm = perm.difference(cycles)
```

Hopefully this will help you out.  I'm open to suggestions and/or corrections.

Comment: Hmm, seems to return `set([(1, 2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2, 1)])` when I run the code rather than (1,1,2,2) and (1,2,1,2) also I'd prefer something not tied to python as I'm actually writing this in C++

Comment: Not sure why the Python tag was included, then.  Was a bit misleading, to be honest.   There are modifications that can be made to give the desired output, but this was more or less a stepping stone, or something to start with.

Comment: OK, yeah see the note I added on the original question as to the python tag (I didn't add it but removing it wrecked all the highlighting, not sure if there's a way around that)

Answer (score 0):

First I'll show the containers and algorithms we'll be `using`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using std::vector;
using std::set;
using std::sort;
using std::next_permutation;
using std::copy;
using std::ostream_iterator;
using std::cout;
```

Next our `vector` which will represent the `Permutation`:

```
typedef vector<unsigned int> Permutation;
```

We need a comparison object to check whether a permutation is a rotation:

```
struct CompareCyclicPermutationsEqual
{
    bool operator()(const Permutation& lhs, const Permutation& rhs);
};
```

And `typedef` a `set` which uses the cyclic comparison object:

```
typedef set<Permutation, CompareCyclicPermutationsEqual> Permutations;
```

Then the main function is quite simple:

```
int main()
{
    Permutation permutation = {1, 2, 1, 2};
    sort(permutation.begin(). permutation.end());

    Permutations permutations;

    do {
        permutations.insert(permutation);
    } while(next_permutation(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()))


    copy(permutations.begin(), permutations.end(),
         ostream_iterator<Permutation>(cout, "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 1, 2, 2,
1, 2, 1, 2,
```

I haven't implemented `CompareCyclicPermutationsEqual` yet. Also you'd need to implement `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Permutation& permutation)`.

Comment: I like how simple this is but isn't it a bit slow? I don't know how the stl set works all that well but I think it's a self balancing BST so wouldn't that be something along the lines of O(L^2 log n) to insert into the set? or can you get it down to O(L log n) using a different method of comparison (I think I came across an O(n) algorithm for rotation comparison but can't find it)?

Comment: It's the fastest C++ implementation on this page yet (c:

Comment: I think inserting at the end of the set would make things better. Will have a think about this tonight.

Comment: What do you mean by inserting at the end of the set? isn't it always inserted in a BST?

Comment: @user1172530 You can give a hint so that it starts comparing where it should be inserted. As the set is sorted lexicographically, and the permutations are the same order, inserting with `end` as a hint will be more efficient.

Comment: Ahh, ok that makes more sense, I'll try coding up one like this and see how the speed compares