# Seating problem - not generating duplicates

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinatorics, circular-permutations

I want to write an algorithm to generate all the possible unique permutations that *n* groups of *m* people can sit around a circular dining table with *mn* seats. An arrangement of diners simply considers the group membership, and doesn't identify individuals within a group. Any two arrangements are considered identical under reflection or rotation.

For example, this is an arrangement with n=4 and m=3 (*edited since there are 4 groups of 3 people*). I have shown it in a square, but the geometry is irrelevant.

```
0 1 2 0
1     3
2     1
3 2 3 0
```

The following arrangements are considered identical to the above:

```
1 2 0 3        0 2 1 0        2 3 2 3
0     1        3     1        1     0 
1     0        1     2        0     1 
2 3 2 3        0 3 2 3        1 2 0 3
```

The strategy I have adopted first is an iterative depth-first search. I store the candidates in a stack, where each candidate is an array of integers. At each iteration I add whichever integers to each candidate array are within the rules. If the required array length is reached then I pop the completed arrangement off the stack and store it in a list. Otherwise I add it back to the stack for further consideration.

The above generates a lot of duplicates. For example, these are all equivalent:

- 0,1,2,0,3,1,0,3,2,3,2,1
- 0,1,2,3,2,3,0,1,3,0,2,1
- 0,1,3,0,2,1,0,1,2,3,2,3
- 0,2,1,0,1,2,3,2,3,0,1,3
- 0,3,1,0,3,2,3,2,1,0,1,2
- 0,3,2,3,2,1,0,1,2,0,3,1
- 1,0,1,2,0,3,1,0,3,2,3,2
- 1,0,1,2,3,2,3,0,1,3,0,2
- 1,0,3,2,3,2,1,0,1,2,0,3
- 1,2,0,3,1,0,3,2,3,2,1,0
- 1,2,3,2,3,0,1,3,0,2,1,0
- 1,3,0,2,1,0,1,2,3,2,3,0
- 2,0,3,1,0,3,2,3,2,1,0,1
- 2,1,0,1,2,0,3,1,0,3,2,3
- 2,1,0,1,2,3,2,3,0,1,3,0
- 2,3,0,1,3,0,2,1,0,1,2,3
- 2,3,2,1,0,1,2,0,3,1,0,3
- 2,3,2,3,0,1,3,0,2,1,0,1
- 3,0,1,3,0,2,1,0,1,2,3,2
- 3,0,2,1,0,1,2,3,2,3,0,1
- 3,1,0,3,2,3,2,1,0,1,2,0
- 3,2,1,0,1,2,0,3,1,0,3,2
- 3,2,3,0,1,3,0,2,1,0,1,2
- 3,2,3,2,1,0,1,2,0,3,1,0

Then, I remove duplicates from the list of arrays generated by the above process. To do this I compare arrays to take into account rotation (by pairwise comparison using an increasing offset) and reflection. This is time-consuming.

**EDIT: Important constraint missed: no two adjacent people may be from the same group.**

My question is this: **how can I speed up the above by avoiding duplicates during the generation process?**  One partial answer is to start by fixing the first element in the array, i.e. insisting that it starts with a zero, since any arrangement can be rotated to have the group signified by zero in a particular position. This is an improvement as it would generate only 6 arrangements in the above case, rather than the whole 24. But, can I do better?

Comment: How are `0,1,2,0,3,1,0,3,2,3,2,1` and `0,1,2,3,2,3,0,1,3,0,2,1` (the first two of your list) equivalent? How can the latter be rotated so that is equal to the prior? For instance the first seating includes `3,1` but there is no way that you can rotate the second to also contain `3,1` At least with what I consider rotating, ie removing an element from the back and inserting it in the front or vice versa.

Comment: There are two different approaches here: (1) Find a faster way to eliminate duplicates; (2) Find a generating method that generates less duplicates.

Comment: For (1), there should be a way to map each array to a "canonical representative" relatively efficiently, so that all duplicates have the same canonical representative. This can be for instance the array which is smallest in lexicographical order.

Comment: For (2), it is ***possible*** that sympy's `bracelets` function does exactly what you want: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.bracelets  But I've never used it and cannot find a precise definition of "bracelet". It does mention that it generates lots of sequences and doesn't generate sequences that are duplicates up to rotation and reflection.

Comment: Running `bracelets(12, 4)` is a bit long, though

Comment: Okay, so apparently `bracelets` doesn't do what you want, because it generates all combinations from [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...] to [3, 3, 3, 3, ...], not just permutations of [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...]. Disappointing.

Comment: See also these related question: [Generating all permutations excluding cyclic rotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028250/generating-all-permutations-excluding-cyclic-rotations) and [Is there an algorithm to generate all unique circular permutations of a multiset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467914/is-there-an-algorithm-to-generate-all-unique-circular-permutations-of-a-multiset?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This is a research paper describing the algorithm you want, and a Haskell implementation of the algorithm in the paper: [A fast algorithm to generate necklaces with fixed content, Joe Sawada, 2003](https://www.cis.uoguelph.ca/~sawada/papers/alph.pdf) and [Haskell: Math.Combinatorics.Multiset.cycles, Brent Yorgey](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-comb-0.2.4.2/docs/Math-Combinatorics-Multiset.html#g:7)

Comment: I'm lost with the first example. You had defined  groups with  indistinguishable members, so I would expect to see  distinct values in the representation, where each of these distinct values represents a group, and thus appears  times. But your example says =3, =4, yet there are 4 distinct values, and each repeats 3 times. Can you clarify?

Comment: @derpirscher a combination of rotation and reflection is allowed. So if you reflect `0,1,2,3,2,3,0,1,3,0,2,1` you get `1,2,0,3,1,0,3,2,3,2,1,0` and the latter is just `0,1,2,0,3,1,0,3,2,3,2,1` shifted along one place.

Comment: @trincot sorry you are correct, it should be n=4 and m=3, edited accordingly

Comment: *"EDIT: Important constraint missed: no two adjacent people may be from the same group."* << This made me laugh out loud

Comment: To include this non-adjacency constraints, you could use the code from my answer, but instead of `from more_itertools import distinct_permutations`, you code your own `distinct_permutations` function, starting from [the source code of more_itertools.distinct_permutations](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#distinct_permutations) and adding the "no adjacency" constraint where appropriate.

Comment: sorry @Stef. When I originally thought of the problem the non adjacency constraint was my main preoccupation. When I discovered just how many duplicates/non-canonical permutations were generated this took away my focus and I omitted it here from my description (which is a shame as it is arguably the most important thing).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing all pairs of arrangements to check whether there is a duplicate in the pair, you can map each arrangement to a canonical representative of all duplicates of this arrangement, and reject every arrangement that is not canonical.

If the arrangements have length `m*n`, but you have `N` arrangements with duplicates, where `m*n` is relatively small but `N` is huge, then comparing all pairs of arrangements would take in the order of `N*N * m*n` operations, whereas filtering out non-canonical arrangements necessitate only `N * m*n` operations.

Also, since the table is circular, you can fix an arbitrary element and consider it to always be the first element. This way, you pass one fewer element to the permutation-generating algorithm, and you immediately avoid generating a lot of duplicates.

Here I generate all seatings with [more_itertools.distinct_permutations](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations), and filter out seatings that are not lexicographically-minimal among their equivalence class of rotations and reflections.

```py
def is_minimal(seq):
    qes = seq[::-1]
    return (
        all(seq <= qes[i:]+qes[:i] for i in range(len(seq))) and
        all(seq <= seq[i:]+seq[:i] for i in range(len(seq)))
    )

from more_itertools import distinct_permutations
from string import printable as alphabet

def seatings(n, m):
    '''all possible seatings for n groups of m people, up to reflection/rotation'''
    pool = '0' * (m-1) + alphabet[1:n] * m
    result = (''.join(('0', *seating)) for seating in distinct_permutations(pool))
    result = [seating for seating in result if is_minimal(seating)]
    return result

l42 = seatings(4, 2)

print(len(l42))
# 171

print(l42)
# ['00112233', '00112323', '00112332', '00113223', '00113232', '00113322', '00121233', '00121323', '00121332', '00122133', '00122313', '00122331', '00123123', '00123132', '00123213', '00123231', '00123312', '00123321', '00131223', '00131232', '00131322', '00132123', '00132132', '00132213', '00132231', '00132312', '00133122', '00133212', '00211233', '00211323', '00211332', '00212133', '00212313', '00213123', '00213132', '00213213', '00213312', '00221133', '00221313', '00223113', '00231123', '00231132', '00231213', '00232113', '00311223', '00312123', '00312213', '00321123', '01012233', '01012323', '01012332', '01013223', '01013232', '01013322', '01021233', '01021323', '01021332', '01022133', '01022313', '01023123', '01023132', '01023213', '01031223', '01032123', '01102233', '01102323', '01102332', '01103223', '01120233', '01120323', '01120332', '01122033', '01122303', '01123023', '01123032', '01123203', '01123302', '01130223', '01130232', '01130322', '01132023', '01132032', '01132203', '01132302', '01133022', '01133202', '01201233', '01201323', '01201332', '01202133', '01202313', '01202331', '01203123', '01203132', '01203213', '01203231', '01203312', '01203321', '01210233', '01210323', '01212033', '01212303', '01213023', '01213032', '01213203', '01213302', '01220133', '01220313', '01220331', '01221033', '01221303', '01223013', '01223031', '01223103', '01230123', '01230132', '01230213', '01230231', '01230312', '01230321', '01231023', '01231032', '01231203', '01231302', '01232013', '01232031', '01232103', '01233102', '01301322', '01302123', '01302132', '01302213', '01302231', '01302312', '01303122', '01303212', '01310223', '01310232', '01312023', '01312032', '01312203', '01312302', '01313022', '01313202', '01320132', '01320213', '01320231', '01320312', '01321203', '01321302', '01323102', '01330212', '01331022', '01331202', '02021133', '02021313', '02023113', '02031123', '02031213', '02112033', '02112303', '02113023', '02113032', '02113203', '02120313', '02121303', '02130213', '02130312', '02131203', '02203113', '02211303']

l43 = seatings(4, 3)

print(len(l43))
# 15402

print(l43)
# ['000111222333', '000111223233', '000111223323', '000111223332', '000111232233', '000111232323', '000111232332', '000111233223', '000111233232', '000111233322', ..., '022121130303', '022203031113', '022211130303']
```

For the record, `distinct_permutations('00111222333')` generates 92400 permutations, of which we keep 15402.

Comment: You can obtain a slight speedup by fixing an arbitrary element to be the first element in your canonical representation, and just prepending that to your `seating`. So `distinct_permutations` produces permutations of length `n-1` (omitting one occurrence of that element), then you prepend your fixed element.

Comment: @DillonDavis Indeed. Couldn't I even remove all n copies of that element from the pool I pass to `distinct_permutations`, so that the permutations are of length `n*(m-1)` instead of `m*n`, and then reinsert the n copies in a smart way?

Comment: I don't think that will eliminate many duplicates. The only extra deduplication which `distinct_permutations` isn't already handling is the flipping/reversing of the permutation. I'm not sure how to eliminate that.