# Generate non-redundant graph patterns

Tags: python-2.7, graph, graph-theory, networkx, python-itertools

I'm trying to generate all possible non-redundant patterns of a complete graph with 4 nodes, using different combinations of nodes. I want to get the linear form of the graph patterns, eg: A-B-C-D.

[Kn complete graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE3jQ.png)

[complete graph pattern of 4 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGbMB.png)

The nodes can be repeated objects, for example, E-E-E-E. For now, I want to test with E and R.

I tried generating patterns using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` and I get 5 patterns:

```
patterns_comb = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(["E","R"],4)]
```

The output is

```
['EEEE', 'EEER', 'EERR', 'ERRR', 'RRRR']
```

Then I use `itertools.product` and I get 16 patterns:

```
patterns_product = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(["E","R"],repeat=4)]
```

The output is:

```
['EEEE', 'EEER', 'EERE', 'EERR', 'EREE', 'ERER', 'ERRE', 'ERRR', 'REEE', 'REER', 'RERE', 'RERR', 'RREE', 'RRER', 'RRRE', 'RRRR']
```

I run a downstream analysis using these patterns. Using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` lead to missing patterns that could be important.
But when using `itertools.product`, there would be redundant patterns, i.e patterns that are producing similar results, so it would take a long time to complete the downstream analysis.

For example: 
ERRE gives the same output as REER (so both are actually the same pattern), and RERE gives the same output as ERER, EERR, RREE.

Is there any solution to get non-redundant patterns or to compare these patterns to see whether they are similar or not?

I tried using `Networkx package` to compare the edges but it is quite hard to compare because of repeated nodes.

Comment: It's not clear what you consider to be different patterns.  Can you give a smaller example (say 3 entries rather than 4) and explain exactly what you want to get?

Comment: I believe in your permutations you consider cyclic rotations of the strings to be equivalent. I've seen this called a [necklace in combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)). If you google some more you can find a few examples in python, e.g. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22938220/604456), [2](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/987433), but I can't vouch for those solutions offhand.